# E2e test report generate in jest and nest.js node

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, nestjs, istanbul

Have used jest --config /path/jest-e2.json --coverage

But it's not generating any files only blank index file. Though test are running. I want to have a report of e2e test.

**e2e setting**

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },

  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage/e2e",
  "coverageReporters" : ["json", "lcov", "text", "clover"],
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    ".module.ts$",
    ".spec.ts$"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Probably the `coverageReporters` have been changed in your `jest-e2.json`. Take a look at [coverageReporters docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options)

Comment: Can you show your test configuration?

Comment: @Teneff have updated the question. please check

Comment: @JayMcDoniel have updated the question. please check

Comment: @varuog try replacing the `coverageDirectory` with `"<rootDir>/coveage/e2e`

Comment: @Teneff still same. generating blank index file with no report data

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue generating coverage for my [Ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) integration tests, it seems Jest won't collect coverage from outside the `rootDir`. To fix this, I set my `rootDir` as my project root (made the [`jest-integration.config.js`](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/main/jest-integration.config.js) on the same level as `package.json`) and told it to only collect coverage from `src/**/*.ts` while ignoring `*.spec.ts` files. Fixed the issue for me (it's a monorepo so the `collectCoverageFrom` structure is slightly different, but the idea is the same)